# Using AutoBogus to set member property value range

Tags: range, faker, bogus

I have the following classes:

```
  Class Person
    Property ID As String = Nothing
    Property Firstname As String = ""
    Property Lastname As String = ""
  End Class

  Class Account
    Property AccountNumber As String = ""
    Property Owners As New List(Of Person)
  End Class
```

I wish to you utilize https://github.com/nickdodd79/AutoBogus to set a range of values from 1,000 to 10,000 for Person.ID when I instantiate an instance of the Account class like so:

```
    Dim fk = AutoFaker.Create()
    Dim acct = fk.Generate(Of Account)
```

Please how may I do this using AutoBogus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution modified from answer provided by Bogus author bchavez at https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus/issues/394.

```
Sub Main
   Dim personFaker = New AutoFaker(Of Person)
   personFaker.RuleFor(Function(p) p.Firstname, Function(f) f.Name.FirstName)
              .RuleFor(Function(p) p.Lastname, Function(f) f.Name.LastName)
              .RuleFor(Function(p) p.ID, Function(f) f.Random.Int(1000,10000).ToString)

   Dim accountFaker = New AutoFaker(Of Account)
   accountFaker.RuleFor(Function(a) a.AccountNumber, Function(f) f.Random.Replace("###############"))
               .RuleFor(Function(a) a.Owners, Function(f) New List(Of Person)(personFaker.GenerateBetween(1,5)))
   accountFaker.Generate().Dump()
End Sub

Class Person
   Property ID As String = Nothing
   Property Firstname As String = ""
   Property Lastname As String = ""
End Class

Class Account
   Property AccountNumber As String = ""
   Property Owners As New List(Of Person)
End Class
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

The original design of AutoBogus was to generate small object graphs for unit tests. Generating the numbers you require could have a performance impact. However, if the above is what you are trying to generate and nothing more complex, then it could be small enough to succeed.

To use AutoBogus out the box you can do the following:

```
Dim acct = AutoFaker.Generate(Of Account, 1000)
```

The second parameter should be the number of accounts you want to create.

AutoBogus uses Bogus under the hood and then leverages Reflection to populate unset properties. If you do see any performance issues, you could use Bogus directly with the caveat that you need define a `RuleFor` for each property. The Bogus [docs](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) provide in-depth details on how to achieve this.

Nick.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Nick. Your answer misinterpreted my question. I wanted to ensure that the values for Person.ID are set to a range of values between 1,000 to 10,000 when the following is executed:

```
    Dim fk = AutoFaker.Create()
    Dim acct = fk.Generate(Of Account)
```

I will post the question to the Bogus GitHub page but I'd also appreciate it if you could still provide an answer with my clarification. Cheers.